# View uploaded file with $_FILES not functioning

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below are the codes in my system to upload student data in .csv file. For now I have only upload file code and the database will only stored the data inside the .csv file. **To view the uploaded file name**, I have put code as `<?php print_r($_FILES) ?>` but the output is as below. Can someone assist me to correct the code?

```
<?php
 
include("mainFunc.php");
 
if(isset($_POST["csv_upload_btn"])) {
    if($_FILES['file']['name']){
        $filename = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
        if($filename[1] == "csv") {
            $failureExists = false;
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle,5000,",")){
 
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[0]);
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[1]);
                $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[2]);
                $item4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[3]);
                $item5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[4]);
                $item6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[5]);
                $item7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[6]);
                $item8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[7]);
                $item9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[8]);
                $item10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[9]);
 
                $query = "INSERT INTO marketing_data(student_matric,student_prg,semester,intake_session,intake_year,student_city,city_lat,city_long,student_state,state_code) VALUES('$item1','$item2','$item3','$item4','$item5','$item6','$item7','$item8','$item9','$item10')";
                $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                if ($run_query == false) {
                    $failureExists = true;
                    echo "<script>alert('File " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . " failed to upload')</script>";
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
            if ($failureExists == false) {
                echo "<script>alert('File " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . " successfully uploaded')</script>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "<script>alert('File " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . " failed to upload. Please upload .csv file.')</script>";
 
        }
    }
}
 
?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
<input type="file" name="file" style="width: 350px";  />
<input type="submit" name="csv_upload_btn" value="Upload" />
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;"><?php print_r($_FILES) ?></div>
</form>
```

***Output***

**=> Array ( [name] => MARKETING_DATA_2018-2020.csv [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpCADB.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 97032 ) )**

Comment: if you want to display the filename this is `<?=$_FILES['file']['name']?>`

Comment: This works... Thank you @MaxMuster :)